# Flutter Linear Gradient Not Displaying

Tags: flutter, linear-gradients

I am trying to add a linear gradient to a container like below:

```
Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        stops: [0.1, 0.5, 0.9],
        colors: [
          Color(0xFFffe9bf),
          Color(0xFFffd280),
          Color(0xFFffb020),
        ],
      ))),
```

it doesn't show up after hot restart and re-install of the app. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Cannot provide both a color and a decoration\nThe color argument is
>   just a shorthand for \"decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: color)\"."

hence remove start by removing the color property in the container

```
Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  width: double.infinity,..
```

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
>   BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
>   The offending constraints were:
>     BoxConstraints(w=661.0, h=Infinity)

you might want to give your container width and height known values either constants or using MediaQuery as shown

```
Container(

  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    stops: [0.1, 0.5, 0.9],
    colors: [
      Color(0xFFffe9bf),
      Color(0xFFffd280),
      Color(0xFFffb020),
    ],
  ))),
```

**result**
[image: result image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake and it turns out I was editing a different screen with copy paste construct from previously designed screens.